# Akka default vs runtime configuration

Tags: configuration, akka

I read the Akka v2.3.11 docs (Java, *not* Scala) and am still a bit confused about how configuration works. In section 2.9.2 ("*Akka and JAR bundling*") it states:

> Akka’s configuration approach relies heavily on the notion of every module/jar having its own reference.conf file, all of these will be discovered by the configuration and loaded. Unfortunately this also means that if you put/merge multiple jars into the same jar, you need to merge all the reference.confs as well. Otherwise all defaults will be lost and Akka will not function.

Being brand new to Akka and actors, but having been a Java developer for 10+ years, I have *never* once before seen a `reference.conf` file in any JAR. So what is Akka talking about here? Are they insinuating that if my Akka project uses, say, Guice and Guava, that I need to define `reference.conf` files for each of these?!?

Also, can someone confirm my understanding of `application.conf` vs `reference.conf`? My *understanding* is that you are supposed to define a `reference.conf` that contains default Akka configs, and then also define an `application.conf` that overrides it? If that's true, why use `reference.conf` in the first place? Why not just use an `application.conf`? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka uses typesafe config library, have a look at the documentation https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/README.md that explains the difference between `reference.conf` and `application.conf`.

Basically `reference.conf` comes with Akka libraries, user shouldn't touch it (but can use as a reference) unless merging multiple jars (not necessary akka jars) that use typesafe config library into one jar.

Comment: Ahh thanks @kostya (+1) - so to confirm: (1) `reference.conf` is only available in Akka libraries (modules/plugins) and the Typesafe config lib knows to override their default values with ones specified in `application.conf`, **yes??** Thanks again!